# Python selenium can't run with chrome v93

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome

yesterday i can run my code successfully with chrome v92.0.4515.107.But after chrome auto updating to v93 today.here's a part of code

```
class CNVD(object):
    def __init__(self):



        self.options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        self.options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation', 'enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=self.options)
        # self.driver.maximize_window()
    def login(self):
        
        #headers设置，缺少会导致session实效
        headers = {
                    'Host':'www.cnvd.org.cn',
                    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36',
                    'Accept':'*/*',
                    'Accept-Language':'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,zh-HK;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.3,en;q=0.2',
                    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
                    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                    'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
                    'Origin':'https://www.cnvd.org.cn',
                    'Referer':'https://www.cnvd.org.cn/user/login'
                    }

        data = 'password=xxxx'
        response = session.post(url="https://www.cnvd.org.cn/user/doLogin/loginForm",data=data,headers=headers)
        response.encoding='utf-8'

        self.driver.get("https://www.cnvd.org.cn")
        self.driver.add_cookie({'name':'__jsl_clearance_s','value':session.cookies.get_dict()['__jsl_clearance_s']})
        self.driver.add_cookie({'name':'JSESSIONID','value':session.cookies.get_dict()['JSESSIONID']})
        self.driver.add_cookie({'name':'__jsluid_s','value':session.cookies.get_dict()['__jsluid_s']})
        self.driver.get("https://www.cnvd.org.cn/user/doLogin/loginForm")
```

i'm sure it can run with chrome v92.0.4515.107.

could somebody help me pls QAQ

Comment: What is the error ? what went wrong ?

Comment: self.driver.get("https://www.cnvd.org.cn/user/doLogin/loginForm")  just return some js coded, but i have already solved it and open the page successfully with chrome v92.0.4515.107 .

Answer (score 0):

If your chrome has automatically updated, then doing the following two steps can hopefully solve your problem.

1. Download updated version of [Chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), which in your case in `ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.15`.
2. Update your following line of your code

```
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'
```

You can obtain the `User-Agent` from network tab in chrome inspect.

Comment: i have tried the first way and didn't work,i will try the second way later.

Comment: You have to do both things simultaneously. Doing one of them will not work.